# Renaming Symfony Bundles from being within a subdirectory

Tags: php, symfony

For a Bundle the default namespace and structure is usually

- src/Acme/DemoBundle/[src]
- AcmeDemoBundle

However, I feel that this naming no longer needs to apply with the project that I'm working on and would like it to just be

- src/AcmeBundle/[src]
- AcmeBundle

I realise that perhaps certain *app/* and *app/config* files will need to be modified. As well as changing *AcmeDemoBundle.php* within the Bundle's directory.

My question is because I cant seem to find anything specifically on the Symfony website about this. Is there an easy way to do this? or just simply go at it and rename and search and replace whatever needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry.  It is a tedious trial&error task, at best.

...but it is the only way to do it (except perhaps dark magic regexps).